# ClickOnce deployment CheckForDetailedUpdate throws an exception

Tags: .net, deployment, windows-7, clickonce, uac

I have an application that's running 24/7 without attendance. It's deployed via [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) and needs to check and download updates by itself. It checks for updates at application startup and at scheduled time at night. When it does it on startup, it works perfectly fine.

However, when it does it at scheduled time, it crashes. In both cases it's using exactly the same piece of code. It's running under Windows 7 and might have something to do with [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control). I'm thinking that maybe it cannot access file system when computer is at idle state? I really need to fix that. Here are the exception details:

Message:

> A privilege that the service requires to function properly does not
>   exist in the service account configuration. You may use the Services
>   Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in (services.msc) and the
>   Local Security Settings MMC snap-in (secpol.msc) to view the service
>   configuration and the account configuration. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070511)

Stack trace:

```
at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.GetAssemblyInformation(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionIdentity DefinitionIdentity, Guid& riid)
at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Store.GetAssemblyManifest(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionIdentity DefinitionIdentity)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetAssemblyManifest(DefinitionIdentity asmId)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(DefinitionIdentity subId)
   at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(SubscriptionState subState)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.BindCoreWithAppId(Boolean blocking, FileStream& refTransaction, String& productName)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.BindCore(Boolean blocking, TempFile& tempDeploy, TempDirectory& tempAppDir, FileStream& refTransaction, String& productName)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.Bind()
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CheckForDetailedUpdate(Boolean persistUpdateCheckResult)
   at AdvancedKiosks.Utils.Updating.Updater.get_UpdateAvailabilityStatus()
   at AdvancedKiosks.Utils.Updating.Updater.get_CanUpdate()
   at AdvancedKiosks.DKMS.ViewModel.MainViewModel.<.ctor>b__6()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

EDIT: I think the cause might be that the hard disk drive is turning off after some time of the system being idle. Is there a way to programatically turn on the hard disk drive before I check for updates (using C#)?

Comment: Open the properties dialog of your Scheduled Task.  There is a setting that is named `When running the task, use the following user account:`.  Is your user account selected?  If not, then this may be the cause of the problem.  Change it to you account and I believe it will fix the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue with a GUI application that detects updates and self-restart.  Every once and again it will crash on restart with this very error.  Since it is running interactively it is (should) be using the current user's account which has Administrative privilege to the system.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio were you using?

Comment: I think it was 2010 but I will not be able to reproduce the problem anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will put this link here just for the record: [link to MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/d9183f7e-f5c7-46d0-8bb4-411ad923976c). According to it, it's a bug in ClickOnce internals which causes this error to appear after certain number of calls to the CheckForDetailedUpdate() function.